# How to implement facebook analytics with Barba.js

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, facebook-analytics, barbajs

I'm using this library called [barba.js](https://barba.js.org/) and trying to implement google analytics and facebook analytics.
I implemented it as mentioned in the official documentation but as barba.js doesn't reload header and footer again and again and just reload the `barba-container` div, which was causing google analytics to record only the pageview on first page where the user lands and not the other pages.
This issue was resolved by calling it in `onEnterCompleted` hook of the views and its resolved.
But the issue I'm facing right now is facebook analytics which is mentioned below.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  cookie     : true,
  xfbml      : true,
  version    : 'v3.3'
});
FB.AppEvents.logPageView();   


};

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

If I take this code in Barba.js view's `onEnterCompleted` hook, it'll be recalled again and again but I'm not sure if this is a best practice or not or if this will work as expected. 
 If someone has implemented facebook analytics with barba.js, please share your example.
Many Thanks !

**EDIT:** I've implemented google analytics this way with barba.js after seeing this [link](https://github.com/barbajs/barba/issues/88).

```
function analytics() {
    var path = (window.location.href).replace(window.location.origin, '').toLowerCase();

    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x', {
        'page_path': path
    });
    console.log('view sent', path);
}
```

I created this function and called it in view's `onEnterCompleted` which resolved the issue with google analytics

Comment: https://github.com/barbajs/barba/issues/88

Comment: Read the question again, I've edited it

Comment: `onEnterCompleted` is not used in the [issue](https://github.com/barbajs/barba/issues/88). why are you sticking with that? Use `initStateChange` instead

Comment: `initStateChange` is never called when the user lands on the website for first time.

Comment: call it directly like `analytics() `

Comment: I've improved my code with this. Thanks for the idea but still it doesn't help with the facebook analytics issue I've mentioned above.